# Select only the newer date using sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with only 3 columns that I am trying to select only the most recent/newer date:

```
account_id -    event_time   -  sign

    2251    2017-03-28 19:00:04  YES
    2250    2017-03-28 15:45:11  NO
    2250    2017-03-28 01:01:45  NO
    2249    2017-03-24 21:00:03  YES
    2248    2017-03-24 05:45:10  NO
    2247    2017-03-19 21:00:05  YES
    2246    2017-03-19 05:45:10  NO
    2245    2017-03-22 21:15:05  YES
```

I am trying to get back these values because they are the newest values in the table:

```
    2251    2017-03-28 19:00:04  YES
    2250    2017-03-28 15:45:11  NO
    2250    2017-03-28 01:01:45  NO
```

I tried:

```
SELECT account_id, max(event_time) as event_time, sign
FROM mytable 
group by account_id,event_time, sign
order by event_time desc
```

But its bring all the records instead.
Has anyone done anything like that?
Thanks for looking!

Comment: What are your rules for selecting those rows? Do you always want the three newest rows?

Comment: No, I need to now the most recent ones, it could be 1, 10, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) to return all records for the latest date:

```
select top 1 with ties
    account_id
  , event_time
  , sign
from mytable
order by convert(date,event_time) desc
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OBPT49409

returns:

```
+------------+---------------------+------+
| account_id |     event_time      | sign |
+------------+---------------------+------+
|       2251 | 2017-03-28 19:00:04 | YES  |
|       2250 | 2017-03-28 15:45:11 | NO   |
|       2250 | 2017-03-28 01:01:45 | NO   |
+------------+---------------------+------+
```

---

For all records for the top 3 dates:

```
select 
    t.account_id
  , t.event_time
  , t.sign
from mytable t
  inner join (
    select distinct top 3 
        convert(date,event_time) as event_time 
    from mytable 
    order by event_time desc
    ) topthree 
      on convert(date,t.event_time) = topthree.event_time
```

returns:

```
+------------+---------------------+------+
| account_id |     event_time      | sign |
+------------+---------------------+------+
|       2251 | 2017-03-28 19:00:04 | YES  |
|       2250 | 2017-03-28 15:45:11 | NO   |
|       2250 | 2017-03-28 01:01:45 | NO   |
|       2249 | 2017-03-24 21:00:03 | YES  |
|       2248 | 2017-03-24 05:45:10 | NO   |
|       2245 | 2017-03-22 21:15:05 | YES  |
+------------+---------------------+------+
```

Comment: I tried that way as well, and I am still getting all the records back instead of the newer ones.

Comment: @Andre I think I see what you want now. Try this update.

Comment: I forgot about "top", I can even get the TWO most dates using it. Great, thank you all for the help!

Comment: I don't know if its too late, but "with ties" rose a question, look at this: http://rextester.com/TOQC12957 - I should get all the records from 28, 27 and 24 according to the docs on with ties, can you confirm? Thanks!

Comment: @Andre Not exactly, you get the top 3 rows but if the 3rd row doesn't have any **ties** then you just get the 3 rows. If you switch to 4 in your test, you'll get back 5 rows because the 4th and 5th row are a tie. -- Quote from the reference above: "The WITH TIES option means that instead of stopping immediately after the requested number of rows is returned, the query will also give you all ties with the last row based on the ordering elements" - Itzik
Ben-Gan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139406/discussion-between-andre-and-sqlzim).

Comment: @Andre: If you want all rows from the TOP 3 dates you must switch to a mix between this and Gordon's answer: `select t.*
from (select t.*,
             DENSE_RANK() over (partition by account_id order by convert(date,event_time) desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t 
where seqnum <= 3
order by event_time desc;`

Comment: I got it to work, you were right, i had to use DENSE_RANK(), my understanding of "with ties" wasn't  correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use subquery

```
select * from yourtable 
    where event_time >= (select convert(date, max(event_time)) from yourtable)
```

With this input

```
create table #yourlog(account_id int, event_time datetime, signin varchar(10))

insert into #yourlog (
account_id ,    event_time   ,  signin)
 values
 (    2251  ,'2017-03-28 19:00:04','YES' )
,(    2250  ,'2017-03-28 15:45:11','NO ' )
,(    2250  ,'2017-03-28 01:01:45','NO ' )
,(    2249  ,'2017-03-24 21:00:03','YES' )
,(    2248  ,'2017-03-24 05:45:10','NO ' )
,(    2247  ,'2017-03-19 21:00:05','YES' )
,(    2246  ,'2017-03-19 05:45:10','NO ' )
,(    2245  ,'2017-03-22 21:15:05','YES' )
```

You get

> account_id    event_time  signin
>
> 2251  2017-03-28 19:00:04.000 YES
>
> 2250  2017-03-28 15:45:11.000 NO
>
> 2250  2017-03-28 01:01:45.000 NO

Comment: On this query, it only return the most recent, I meant only 1 record gets back when I have 3 records with the newest date in the table based on the data sample I posted.

Comment: You will get the output which you provided in the example. Edited my answer to add those info...

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by account_id order by event_time desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t 
where seqnum = 1
order by event_time desc;
```

Comment: Still, tried it,  I am still getting all the records back instead of the newer ones.

Comment: @Andre . . . This query will return only one row per `account_id` and the should be the newest row for the account.  That appears to be what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT top 3 *
  FROM mytable 
 ORDER BY event_time DESC
```

Comment: Can't use that, it might be more or less than 3 records in the table per newer date.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then Kannan Kandasamy's answer should work as it returns all entries from the last day if this is what you want.

Comment: No, it only returns the most recent record not all of them, it should return 3 records.

Comment: No, it returns all rows from 2017-03-28, given the shown data is the data you are using.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.